# Jenkins CORS Filter plugin not adding Access-Control-Allow-Origins header

Tags: rest, jenkins, cors, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to add CORS support to my Jenkins server so I could access the REST API from the browser. From looking around, the recommended approach is to use the [CORS Filter plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cors-filter-plugin).

I have installed it, enable it, and add `http://localhost` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origins` field, as well as `GET` to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` field. However, these headers are not showing up in my requests.

This plugin has not been updated in a few years, so I'm not sure if it's compatible with the latest version of Jenkins. I'm running version 2.172.

In the Jenkins system log, I see these errors, not sure if it's related/ relevant

```
Caught exception evaluating: descriptor.getPropertyType(instance,field).itemTypeDescriptorOrDie in /configure. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.AssertionError: class hudson.ivy.IvyBuildTrigger$IvyConfiguration is missing its descriptor in public hudson.ivy.IvyBuildTrigger$IvyConfiguration[] hudson.ivy.IvyBuildTrigger$DescriptorImpl.getConfigurations(). See https://jenkins.io/redirect/developer/class-is-missing-descriptor
```

```
Caught exception evaluating: h.filterDescriptors(it,attrs.descriptors) in /configure. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class hudson.model.Hudson' in thread 'Handling GET /configure from 100.71.26.18 : qtp589873731-14 Jenkins/configure.jelly GlobalLibraries/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
java.lang.NullPointerException: Descriptor list is null for context 'class hudson.model.Hudson' in thread 'Handling GET /configure from 100.71.26.18 : qtp589873731-14 Jenkins/configure.jelly GlobalLibraries/config.jelly LibraryConfiguration/config.jelly SCMRetriever/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly MultiSCM/DescriptorImpl/config.jelly'
```

These errors have `at org.jenkinsci.plugins.corsfilter.AccessControlsFilter.doFilter(AccessControlsFilter.java:79)` in their stack trace.

Does anyone know of a good way to enable CORS support for Jenkins REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins version 2.303 and I struggle with the same issue. I would recommend to **add the port number** on the localhost URI you defined in the plugin settings, even though I'm pretty sure that won't change anything.
It actually seems the plugin is having no effect at all.

Probably the best solution is to set up your own proxy which would take care of CORS. Here is a good and well document example [Build a Node.js Proxy Server in Under 10 minutes!](https://www.twilio.com/blog/node-js-proxy-server)