# Jenkins Cors Plugin not enabling Access-Control-Allow-Header

Tags: jenkins, cors, jenkins-plugins

i am trying to access the API of my jenkins server through a javascript application to get some build data. When trying to make the request, i get a CORS error, despite me having the CORS plugin enabled for jenkins

Here is the error i get in the console `Access to fetch at (my_jenkins_server) from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

In the fetch i include the following headers:

`headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type':  'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('jenkin_user:jenkin_token')`

And this is the current setting for my CORS plugin
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOEkk.png)

Similar to this question here [Jenkins CORS Filter plugin not adding Access-Control-Allow-Origins header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962278/jenkins-cors-filter-plugin-not-adding-access-control-allow-origins-header)